# ¿Se puede poner el onclick en javascript en vez de en el html?

Tags: javascript, html

soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo Javascript, estoy intentando hacer una calculadora y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poner el evento onclick desde javascript y no tener que escribirlo en el html, en el código tengo el onclick en el html pero me gustaría quitarlo de ahí y ponerlo en un archivo js.

Tambien me gustaría saber por que cuando declaro las variables fuera de la función y intento acceder al valor de estas en una función en la consola me aparece que el valor es null y sale un error pero cuando declaro las variables dentro de la función si me funciona perfectamente.

De antemano muchas gracias.

```js
let numero2= document.getElementById("2");
let numero3= document.getElementById("3");
let numero4= document.getElementById("4");
let numero6= document.getElementById("6");
let numero5= document.getElementById("5");
let numero7= document.getElementById("7");
let numero8= document.getElementById("8");
let numero9= document.getElementById("9");
let numero0= document.getElementById("0");
let tipotexto= document.getElementById("cuatro");
function uno(){
    let numero1= document.getElementById("1");
    let tipotexto= document.getElementById("cuatro");
    tipotexto.value=numero1.value;
}

numero1.onclick.function(){
    let numero1= document.getElementById("1");
    let tipotexto= document.getElementById("cuatro");
    tipotexto.value=numero1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" class="texto" id="cuatro">
<input type="button" name="" value="1"class="buton" id="1" onclick="uno();">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me supondré que aún no conoces sobre los `listener`, así que te explicaré de una forma sencilla.

Con el `onclick` en tu botón, estás indicando que cuando hagamos clic en el botón, se ejecutará cierta función. Este `onclick` es un evento que ocurre cuando le hagamos clic.

Ahora, existe una forma de poder escuchar estos eventos desde JavaScript sin necesidad de poner `onclick` en el botón, sería usar el método `addEventListener`.

Como dice la [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> ***addEventListener()** Registra un evento a un objeto en específico. El Objeto especifico puede ser un simple elemento en un archivo, el mismo documento , una ventana o un XMLHttpRequest.*
>
> *Para registrar más de un eventListener, puedes llamar addEventListener() para el mismo elemento pero con diferentes tipos de eventos o parámetros de captura.*

---

En pocas palabras, con `addEventListener` podemos escuchar los eventos que ocurre en  cierto elemento, y una vez ocurra, se ejecutan dichas instrucciones. Por ejemplo, capturemos a tu botón:

```js
let numero1 = document.getElementById('1'); // capturo el botón
```

Y a ese botón, podemos escuchar los eventos que ocurra, en este caso, cuando ocurra el `click`, y una vez ocurra eso, ejecuta a la función `uno` (que es el segundo parámetro del listener):

```js
numero1.addEventListener("click", uno) // escucho el evento "click" en el botón "numero1"
```

Y con esto, llamas a la función sin necesidad de tener `onclick` en tu HTML.

```js
let tipotexto = document.getElementById('cuatro');
let numero1 = document.getElementById('1'); // capturo el botón

numero1.addEventListener("click", uno) // escucho el evento "click" en el botón "numero1"

function uno() {
  tipotexto.value = numero1.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" class="texto" id="cuatro">
<input type="button" name="" value="1" class="buton" id="1">
```

Comment: si, me imagine... suelo hacer lo mismo!!