# JavaScript- ¿Como cambiar el tamaño de fuente de un elemento HTML cuando se presiona una tecla en el teclado?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer zoom al mensaje que le inyecte a mi HTML

```
BOTON.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  DIV.innerHTML="Mensaje agregado al Div";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

el siguiente código esta comentado y explica como cambiar el tamaño de la fuente de un DIV según una tecla presionada.

Nota: En un teclado de estilo QWERTY funcionará adecuadamente pero si el teclado no fuera QWERTY podría no funcionar y deberás aplicar otro tipo de solución como por ejemplo la que se menciona acá [getLayoutMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Keyboard/getLayoutMap#browser_compatibility), pero lamentablemente aún no es compatible con todos los navegadores a día de hoy.

```js
//creamos una constante de nuestro elemento a utilizar para referenciarlo más comodamente 
const log = document.getElementById("log");

//creamos un evento de escucha global utilizando "document"
//el evento es de tipo "keypress" para escuchar los evento de presionar teclas 
document.addEventListener("keypress", logKey);

//creamos una función que reacciona al evento de keypress en el documento
function logKey(e) {
  //agregamos un texto al "div con id=log" con la tecla presionada 
  log.textContent += ` ${e.code}`;
  //al activarse el evento, podemos cambiar el tamaño de la fuente
  log.style.fontSize = "40px";
  //o podemos cambiar el tamaño según alguna tecla en específico
  //con un "if" podemos definir acciones a realizar según una tecla presionada
  //por ejemplo que la fuente sea de 25px en el "div de id=log"
  if (e.code == "KeyA")
    log.style.fontSize = "25px";

  //acá por ejemplo que la fuente sea de 12px en el "div de id=log"
  if (e.code == "KeyS")
    log.style.fontSize = "12px";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <label for="sample">Pulsa la tecla "A" para fuente de 25px y "S" para fuente de 12px:</label>
   <div id="log"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Más simple, puedes hacerlo con `switch` `case`, en donde el parámetro del `switch` es la tecla que presionamos (que será identificada con `event.key`), y dependiendo a qué tecla sea, ingresa a un `case`, y ahí asignamos el valor de la variable `tamanio`, que será quien modificará el tamaño de la letra con `texto.style.fontSize = tamanio;`. Este comportamiento ocurre cada vez que se presiona la tecla <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> y <kbd>D</kbd>, gracias al `listener` y el `keypress`.

---

Para que lo entiendas mejor, cuando presionamos cualquier tecla, ocurre el `keypress` y llamo al `listener`, quien se encarga de ejecutar a la función `nuevoTamanioLetra()`, y el `switch` de esa función se encarga de evaluar si la tecla que presionamos entran a alguno de los `case` (o sea si son `a`, `s` o `d`), de lo contrario, ingresa al `default`, haciendo solo un `return`.

[***Más información sobre los listener.***](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/585280/262104)

---

**Demo:**

```js
function nuevoTamanioLetra(event) {
  let texto = document.getElementById("texto");
  let tecla = event.key;
  let tamanio = "";
  switch(tecla) {
    case "a":
      tamanio = "12px";
      break;
    case "s":
      tamanio = "16px";
      break;
    case "d":
      tamanio = "20px";
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  texto.style.fontSize = tamanio;
}

document.addEventListener("keypress", nuevoTamanioLetra);
```

```html
<p id="texto">Párrafo de ejemplo.</p>
```