# ¿Cómo cambiar el tamaño de fuente de un elemento html con una función en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Debo crear una función que cambie el tamaño de fuente de un elemento HTML cuando se presiona una tecla en el teclado. Agrega esta función como un listener de evento para un div del html.

Este es el último código que probé pero no se genera ningún cambio

```
function cambiarTamanoFuente(evento) {
    const div = document.getElementById("miDiv");
    div.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
      
            if (evento.key === 1) {
              div.style.fontSize = "larger";
            } else if (evento.key === 0) {
              div.style.fontSize = "smaller";
            }          
    })
  }
   cambiarTamanoFuente("keydown");
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [JavaScript- ¿Como cambiar el tamaño de fuente de un elemento HTML cuando se presiona una tecla en el teclado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/592209/javascript-como-cambiar-el-tama%c3%b1o-de-fuente-de-un-elemento-html-cuando-se-pres)

Comment: Si son compañeros de clase, pónganse de acuerdo para no preguntar lo mismo. Por cierto, debes crear un [example].

Answer (score 0):

```js
const div = document.getElementById( "miDiv" );

  // ponemos un listener al documento, pasamos el evento como parámetro a la función. 
document.addEventListener( "keydown", function( evento ) {
    
      // comprobamos que la tecla apretada sea el "1" (del qwerty)
    if( evento.code == "Digit1" ) {
          // asignamos el nuevo tamaño
        div.style.fontSize = "24px";
    } 
    else if( evento.code === "Digit2" ) {
        div.style.fontSize = "28px";
    }  
    else {
          // averiguamos el code de otras teclas
        console.log( evento.code );
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="miDiv"> Holis </div>
```

Como verás, **cambiarTamanoFuente( "keydown" );** lo eliminé, porque no tiene sentido, ya que le pusiste un listener al documento.